# How to save file attachement in sql server in bot framework

Tags: c#, botframework

```
        var url = state.Image.Attachment.ContentUrl;
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var imageData = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(url);

 string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ASPNETConnectionString"].ToString();
                    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr);

                    string sql = "INSERT into dbo.mee (name,image,status,guid) VALUES ('" + name + "','" + imageData + "','" + status + "','" + g + "');";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql);
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    try
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        await context.PostAsync($"Your details has been received");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        await context.PostAsync($"cannot connect to database");

                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                 };

    I want to save the image attachment uploaded by the user to sql server database. I used the imageData variable in my sql statement but the image would not save. I have already used varbinary(max) as the data type in my sql table. is there anything wrong with the code above? please i need help.
```

I have added the sql code. when i removed the image variable from the data, the sql statement executed successfully then i knew something is wrong with the image data

Comment: What is the content size of the imageData variable? Add the code you use to save the data in the database.

Comment: i have added the sql statement and explained further the image size is less than 100mb

Comment: You cannot (and shouldn't) just concat the values you want to save in your SQL query. Use prepared statements instead, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `the image size is less than 100mb` Hi @OluwatosinSamuelBabalola, if possible, you can try to store the attachment file in Azure storage and save the URL of attachment file in your SQL database instead of storing large file in database directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
       var url = state.Image.Attachment.ContentUrl;
       var httpClient = new HttpClient();
       StorageFile f1 = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(url);
       string imageData = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(f1.Path));
```

I converted image to Base64.

Comment: what namespace should i install to access StorageFile?

Comment: System.Windows.storage,System.Windows

Comment: i downloaded the package but was given error while trying to add it to References in my project

Comment: There are several different versions that should fit with your operating system. You will find other sites you will find.